# How can I truncate a string to have at most N characters?

Tags: string, unicode, rust, truncate

The expected approach of [`String.truncate(usize)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.truncate) fails because it doesn't consider Unicode characters (which is baffling considering Rust treats strings as Unicode).

```
let mut s = "ボルテックス".to_string();
s.truncate(4);
```

> thread '' panicked at 'assertion failed: self.is_char_boundary(new_len)'

Additionally, `truncate` modifies the original string, which is not always desired.

The best I've come up with is to convert to `char`s and collect into a `String`.

```
fn truncate(s: String, max_width: usize) -> String {
    s.chars().take(max_width).collect()
}
```

e.g.

```
fn main() {
    assert_eq!(truncate("ボルテックス".to_string(), 0), "");
    assert_eq!(truncate("ボルテックス".to_string(), 4), "ボルテッ");
    assert_eq!(truncate("ボルテックス".to_string(), 100), "ボルテックス");
    assert_eq!(truncate("hello".to_string(), 4), "hell");
}
```

However this feels very heavy handed.

Comment: Unicode is freaking complicated. Are you sure you want `char` (which corresponds to code points) as unit and not grapheme clusters?

Comment: Actually, the other direction is just as valid: Impose a limit on the number of *bytes* the UTF-8 encoding takes (you need some care to chop off whole characters &mdash; take as many `char`s as possible without going over N bytes). While this does not match people's perception of character counts, it is reasonable when the restriction is storage-motivated (e.g., the size of a database column).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make sure you read and understand [delnan's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461429/how-to-truncate-string-to-have-at-most-n-characters#comment64327244_38461429):

> Unicode is freaking complicated. Are you sure you want `char` (which corresponds to code points) as unit and not grapheme clusters?

**The rest of this answer assumes you have a good reason for using `char` and not graphemes**.

> which is baffling considering Rust treats strings as Unicode

This is not correct; Rust treats strings as **UTF-8**. In UTF-8, every code point is mapped to a variable number of bytes. There's no `O(1)` algorithm to convert "6 characters" to "N bytes", so the standard library doesn't hide that from you.

You can use `char_indices` to step through the string character by character and get the byte index of that character:

```
fn truncate(s: &str, max_chars: usize) -> &str {
    match s.char_indices().nth(max_chars) {
        None => s,
        Some((idx, _)) => &s[..idx],
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(truncate("ボルテックス", 0), "");
    assert_eq!(truncate("ボルテックス", 4), "ボルテッ");
    assert_eq!(truncate("ボルテックス", 100), "ボルテックス");
    assert_eq!(truncate("hello", 4), "hell");
}
```

This also returns a slice that you can choose to move into a new allocation if you need to, or mutate a `String` in place:

```
// May not be as efficient as inlining the code...
fn truncate_in_place(s: &mut String, max_chars: usize) {
    let bytes = truncate(&s, max_chars).len();
    s.truncate(bytes);
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = "ボルテックス".to_string();
    truncate_in_place(&mut s, 0);
    assert_eq!(s, "");
}
```

Comment: How is using `char_indices()` different from my use of `chars()`?

Comment: @Peter `chars` only returns the characters. `char_indices` is similar in concept to `chars().enumerate()` except it returns the actual index of the `u8` that character starts at in the original `str`.

Comment: `.skip(max_chars).next()` → `.nth(max_chars)`.

Comment: @Veedrac Every. Single. Time. I will never remember it! [Clippy feature request](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/issues/1112)!