# How do I remove some chars at the end of a string?

Tags: string, rust

I need to match a few words in the start of a string, handle it, than removes it. How should I remove few chars or bytes in then end of a`String`?

I using `regex` crate to match the string. I can't find a way to remove chars in the end of the `String`.

Maybe something like this, but have non-ASCII chars:

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use regex::Regex;
fn func(s: &mut String) {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref RE: Regex = Regex::new(r"123").unwrap();
    }
    let cap = match RE.captures(s.as_str()) {
        Some(v) => v.get(0).unwrap(),
        None => panic!("Error"),
    };
    do_something(cap.as_str());
    s.delete(0, cap.end());
}
fn do_something(s: &str) {
    assert_eq!(s, "123")
}
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("123456");
    func(s);
    assert_eq!(s, "456");
}
```

I have seen `remove` method, but it says it's `O(n)`. If it is, I think `O(nm)` is a little bit too slow for me.

Comment: Your text says 'remove in the end of the string', Your code asserts that text from the beginning got removed. Which one do you need? The latter is not possible in better than `O(n)`

Comment: super sorry about type it wrong. I mean `String::remove` only delete 1 char at a time, if I call it many times, it will cost `O(nm)` time. `O(n)` ok, but no `O(nm)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexes [`Match::start`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.7.0/regex/struct.Match.html#method.start) to get a start of the capture group.

You can then use [`truncate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.truncate) to get rid of everything after that.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut text: String = "this is a text with some garbage after!abc".into();
    let re = regex::Regex::new("abc$").unwrap();
    let m = re.captures(&text).unwrap();
    let g = m.get(0).unwrap();
    text.truncate(g.start());
    dbg!(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`truncate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.truncate) - except with non-ascii support.

For ascii only, this works:

```rust
let mut s = String::from("123456789");
s.truncate(s.len() - 3);
assert_eq!(s, "123456");
```

However since `String` can contain unicode characters which aren't always 1 byte, it doesn't work for non-ascii (panics if the new length does not lie on a char boundary)

If you want non-ascii support, there isn't an `O(1)` solution [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461429/how-can-i-truncate-a-string-to-have-at-most-n-characters). That answer does give an implementation using `char_indicies()`, I think it's the best way unless I'm missing something.

There is also the [unicode-truncate](https://docs.rs/unicode-truncate/latest/unicode_truncate/) crate, which also seems to use `char_indicies()` - might be worth a look.